# Corner effect when using different lines for creating an Inkscape figure

Tags: inkscape, corners

With Inkscape, when using two different lines for creating one entire figure, the result is this by default:

[image: Wrong corner]

What I want to achieve is, normally:

[image: Correct corner]

The problem is the same even when the angle is not 90-degrees (acute and obtuse angles). How to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you should reveal a little more of your actual drawing goal. It's very difficult to see why try something complex when the visible goal needs only three clicks with the Pen (+holding Ctrl to get exactly horizontal and vertical lines).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have two separate paths, which are not joined.  You must join them if you want a mitre join at the corner.

You can do one of the following

1. Join the lines at the corner by selecting both paths using the Edit Nodes by Paths tool <kbd>F2</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click and drag around the two nodes you wan to join, and hit Join <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
2. Use the Bézier tool to make one complete path with a corner node. Tip: Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click with the Bézier tool to constrain the angles of the lines.

Examples

[image]

Comment: I am interested in the first solution. so, I select the two lines (or objects) I want to join then I click `Shift`+`J`. Nothing happens. Instead of a shortcut, is there a way of doing it by clicking `path > join` or something like this?

Comment: How did you create the lines?  Are they single paths? Did you make them in Inkscape? Do you have some effect applied to them?

Comment: No effect on them. They are arrows to be exact

Comment: What do you mean by arrows?  Did you create them in Inkscape?  Can you [share the SVG on SVGShare](http://svgshare.com/)?

Comment: > stroke style > End Markers. I can share

Comment: https://svgshare.com/i/K1P.svg

Comment: The vertical arrow is messed up.  It seems to be made of a closed path. Delete it and draw another one.  It must be a single path with two end nodes, or you won't be able to join it to the horizontal arrow. You can't join a closed path to an open path.